# How to execute the function in a tkinter sub window by the tkinter main window

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, ttkbootstrap

In Tkinter, how can I execute a function in a subwindow (Toplevel window) from the main window? In the code below, after I click the sayHelloInNewWindow button from the main window, I expected it to print a label that say Hello in a new window.

```
import ttkbootstrap as tb
import tkinter as tk

class Main():
    def __init__(self, window):
        # Window
        window.title("Main") # Set the window title
        window.geometry("480x720") # Set window size  

        createWindowButton = tb.Button(window, text="Create a window", command=self.new_window)
        createWindowButton.pack(side="top")

        sayHelloInNewWindow = tb.Button(window, text="Say Hello in New Window", command=self.newtab.sayhello)
        sayHelloInNewWindow.pack(side="bottom")

    def new_window(self):
        self.newtab = NewWindow(tk.Toplevel(window))


class NewWindow():
    def __init__(self, window):
        window.title("New Window")
        window.geometry("480x720") # Set window size  
    def sayhello(self):
        helloLabel = tb.Label(window, text="Hello")
        helloLabel.pack(side="top")

if __name__ == "__main__":  # only runs when this file is run as a standalone
    theme = "cyborg"
    window = tb.Window(themename=theme)        # create a TK object
    Main(window)     # open the VideoPlayer GUI
    window.mainloop()       # run the window main loop, reacting to button presses, etc
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better that `Main` inherits from `tb.Window` and `NewWindow` inherits from `tb.Toplevel`.  Also you need to check whether the *self.newtab* is created if you want to call its function `sayhello()`.

Below is the modified code:

```py
import ttkbootstrap as tb

class Main(tb.Window):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.title("Main") # Set the window title
        self.geometry("480x720") # Set window size

        # initialize self.newtab
        self.newtab = None

        createWindowButton = tb.Button(self, text="Create a window", command=self.new_window)
        createWindowButton.pack(side="top")

        sayHelloInNewWindow = tb.Button(self, text="Say Hello in New Window", command=self.newtab_sayhello)
        sayHelloInNewWindow.pack(side="bottom")

    def newtab_sayhello(self):
        if self.newtab and self.newtab.winfo_exists():
            # the window is open, so call its sayhello()
            self.newtab.sayhello()

    def new_window(self):
        if self.newtab is None or not self.newtab.winfo_exists():
            # the window is not created or closed
            # so create new one
            self.newtab = NewWindow(self)
        else:
            # the window is already open
            # so bring it to front
            self.newtab.lift()


class NewWindow(tb.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.title("New Window")
        self.geometry("480x720") # Set window size

    def sayhello(self):
        helloLabel = tb.Label(self, text="Hello")
        helloLabel.pack(side="top")

if __name__ == "__main__":  # only runs when this file is run as a standalone
    theme = "cyborg"
    window = Main(themename=theme)
    window.mainloop()
```